# pgRouting: weight routes with similar attributes higher

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am creating my own routable network using pgRouting. I would like my shortest path queries to prefer a route made up of the same attribute.

For example, in the image below (please excuse my terrible drawing), I don't necessarily care if the best route is made up of either A or B as long as it's only A or only B.

[image]

Comment: i think you need to have 2 cost columns in routing table , one is calculated so it prefers A attribute (CASE WHEN B=x then -1 ..) and other is calculated using B, then you need make shortest distance query twice to get best route.

Comment: Do you have some sample records? By the sounds of it, you've got multiple links to the same nodes (with the same cost?)... In that case one approach might be to identify those nodes, and delete those links which don't share the same attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a think about this and I think I've got something.

A lot depends on how complex your network is. I.e. do you have other links connecting to the nodes? Are the routes A and B identical? Etc. Anyway, I've assumed you can just take the route for the "first" attribute. My solution relies on looking at two connected links. Here goes...

Step one. You need the links table with a unique id column and two boolean columns to show duplicates, and whether to keep the link.

```
CREATE TABLE mynetwork(
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
from_node INTEGER,
to_node INTEGER,
my_attribute TEXT,
duplicate_flag BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
keep_link BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE);
```

I've now added some records. The route 1 - 2 - 3 is a duplicate, so we need to pick either A or B. The route 1 - 4 - 5 can only be completely reached with B (i.e. we need to ignore the A version of 1 - 4).

```
INSERT INTO mynetwork(from_node,to_node,my_attribute)
VALUES 
(1,2,'A'), -- 1 to 3 via 2 is a duplicate
(2,3,'A'),
(1,2,'B'),
(2,3,'B'),
(2,6,'C'), -- a link to a "middle" node. This needs to be reachable via A or B
(1,4,'A'), -- a route that can only be reached via mixed attributes.
(4,5,'B'), -- The route we need here is B
(1,4,'B');
```

Step 2 identify those route fragments which have duplicates. Put the results into a temporary table. [EDIT simplified this a bit - can identify the first attribute here already]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_duplicate_routes;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_duplicate_routes AS
-- This query finds duplicate route fragments
SELECT a.id as m1_id,b.id as m2_id, a.from_node as thestart,a.to_node AS themiddle,b.to_node as theend, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY a.to_node ORDER BY a.my_attribute)
FROM mynetwork a
INNER JOIN mynetwork b
ON b.from_node = a.to_node AND a.my_attribute = b.my_attribute;
-- if this table is large, add indexes here
```

Step 3 update the "duplicates" flag. Theses are all links with a from_node or to_node matching the middle node in the temp table.

```
UPDATE mynetwork
SET duplicate_flag = TRUE FROM tmp_duplicate_routes d
WHERE (thestart = from_node AND themiddle = to_node)
OR (themiddle = from_node AND theend = to_node)
```

Step 4 get the first attribute for each route fragment where the attribute is the same for the entire route and put  the ids for those links into one column; update the "Keep_link" column.

```
WITH 
links_to_keep as -- 
(SELECT m1_id as id_to_keep FROM tmp_duplicate_routes WHERE row_number = 1
UNION
SELECT m2_id as id_to_keep FROM tmp_duplicate_routes WHERE row_number = 1)

UPDATE mynetwork SET keep_link = TRUE WHERE id in (SELECT id_to_keep from links_to_keep);
```

Now, you can either delete or otherwise knock out all the records with duplicate_flag TRUE and keep_link FALSE.

The queries above won't handle the following complicated scenario. 1 - 2 - 3 is a choice between A or B. 3 - 4- 5 is a choice between B and C. So... 1 - 5 should be "B"; the queries above will set 1-3 as A and 3-5 as B. Hopefully you don't have that scenario. And I really don't know what would happen if you have A and B for 1 - 2 - 3, then B and C for 2 - 3 - 4...

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution. I tested out your approach and it does work for selecting a line with only one attribute, so nice job!  Unfortunately I do have a more complex dataset where multiple routes partially overlap and branch off into different directions. I also would like to indicate that either A or B is an option for the 1-2-3 path, without deleting one of them.  This is a helpful starting point and answers my question though, so thanks again. I'll post if I come up with a solution for the more complex network.